# Equivalent to C#'s Semaphore/SemaphoreSlim in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

Is there an equivalent to C#'s Semaphore/SemaphoreSlim type, in Kotlin? I would like to use it with co-routines (non-blocking). I.e. WaitOneAsync().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`kotlinx-coroutines` now has a full-fledged [`Semaphore`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.sync/-semaphore/) class.

You can use it as follows:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.async
import kotlinx.coroutines.awaitAll
import kotlinx.coroutines.sync.Semaphore
import kotlinx.coroutines.sync.withPermit


suspend fun doConcurrently(list: List<Something>) {
    val semaphore = Semaphore(4) // number of permits is 4

    list
        .map { async { semaphore.withPermit { /* do something */ } } }
        .awaitAll()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options coming from Java.
Most common would be to use `CountDownLatch`:

```
val latch = CountDownLatch(1)

async {
   // Do something
   latch.countDown()
}

latch.await()
```

Usually that's enough.
If you have some very specific cases, you can also use semaphore, of course:

```
launch {
    try {
        semaphore.acquire()
        // Do something
    }
    finally {
        semaphore.release()
    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding the first example with the CountDownLatch: isn't it blocking (yes, it's running on a different thread, but it's blocking that thread)? And the second example: where is the semaphore variable coming from? :)

Comment: I found a non-blocking version here of CountDownLatch! https://github.com/venkatperi/kotlin-coroutines-lib/blob/e3c919b2eb4eabef944da20197d70cdb7bd28119/src/main/kotlin/com/vperi/kotlinx/coroutines/experimental/sync/CountDownLatch.kt

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using Kotlin's own `Job.join()` method. The benefit is that `join` is a `suspsend` function and there is no need for extra `async` block

```
val latch: CompletableJob = Job()

launch {
    latch.join()
}
```

And when ready call:

```
latch.complete()
```

Also if you need timeouts you can wrap `join` call into `withTimeout` or `withTimeoutOrNull`

Another useful Kotlin interface is `CompletableDeferred`. Unlike `Job` it returns completion result. See its `await/complete` methods